# SwiftUI: unwanted split view on iPad

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, xcode11

Problem: a view on Pad shows up with ***unwanted*** split view.

My current setup is:
Catalina OSX beta 5 + 
Xcode 11 Beta 5

Here is the code I used, with a Navigation View and a Navigation Title:

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct SwiftUIView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Text("Search")
                .navigationBarTitle(Text("Search"))
        }
    }
}

#if DEBUG
struct SwiftUIView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        SwiftUIView()
    }
}
#endif
```

When simulated on iPad (both physical device and preview) instead of a full screen view, I get this split screen view:

[image: Unwanted split view with NavigationView]

If I have just a view, with no NavigationView, I get a full screen view:

```
import SwiftUI

struct SwiftUIView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello World!")
    }
}

#if DEBUG
struct SwiftUIView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        SwiftUIView()
    }
}
#endif
```

[image: Full screen, but without NavigationView]

How can I make a NavigationView full screen (not split screen) on iPad?

Answer (score 214, accepted):

**Update July 2022**

Using `NavigationStack` instead of `NavigationView` should display as the main view as you would expect on iPad:

```swift
NavigationStack {
    Text("Hello world!")
}
```

*In newer versions, the `navigationViewStyle` modifier has been [deprecated](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/navigationviewstyle).

**Original answer:**

You can apply the `.navigationViewStyle(.stack)` modifier to the NavigationView.

```
... 
    NavigationView {
        Text("Hello world!")
    }
    .navigationViewStyle(.stack)
...
```

Edit: Below, I am answering Alexandre's questions from his comment:

- *Why full view is not the default for iPad?* That's just a choice made by Apple...
- *Why this modifier goes outside of NavigationView closure, while the Navigation Title goes inside...* Maybe this gives clarification: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57400873/11432719

Comment: Perfect, thanks mate!

What I find confusing, is:

 - Why full view is not the default for iPad.
- Why this modifier goes outside of NavigationView closure, while the Navigation Title goes inside...

Thanks again! : )

Comment: Is there a way to change the StackNavigationViewStyle dynamically? I want to be able to navigate from `column1 -> column2 -> fullscreen`.

Comment: @SimonBachmann I guess it’s possible, when I have time I will figure it out and let you know.

Comment: Not available on macOS, anyone have any idea what to do there?

Comment: Works like Charm 

Answer (score 8):

To use this split style for **iPad** but remove for **iPhone**:

```
extension View{
    func phoneOnlyStackNavigationView() ->some View {
        if UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .phone{
            return AnyView(self.navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle()))
        } else {
            return AnyView(self)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: By default, iPad navigationViewStyle isn't Stack but iPhone default navigationViewStyle is Stack. Its automatic.

Comment: Not really, on iPhone XR and 11 for instance, the default navigationViewStyle is DoubleColumn. This code snippet essentially forces the stack style on those classes of iPhone.

Comment: This might be me going crazy, but where do I call this function?

Comment: @SwiftUser on the body of your SwiftUI view like any other view modifier.