# SwiftUI - Navigation View opening with Back button and half grey screen / weird behavior

Tags: swift, swiftui, ios-navigationview, swiftui-navigationview

I am trying to add navigation view to my app, but it is causing issues. My main UI is an infinitely swipe-able carousel of pages. It originally looks like this: [image: swipable pages without navigation view]

Then when I wrap it in a navigation view, it opens like this, with a back button and nothing else: [image]

When I hit the back button, it looks like this:[image]

The left side is swipe-able like the original UI, but when I touch the right, grey side, it takes me back to the empty page with the back button.

Any idea what may be causing this? I implemented the infinite carousel by putting each page in a ZStack, and using offsets/relativeLocation. I referred to this tutorial:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fB5MzDD1PZI

Can I not use a NavigationView? Is there an alternative route I can take in which I create my own top NavBar and navigate to separate views without NavigationBar/NavigationLink?

Any help is appreciated and please feel free to ask questions, etc. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to apply `StackNavigationViewStyle` to your `NavigationView`.

```
NavigationView {

...

}.navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())
```

You're experiencing an unwanted split view, and you can find more info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57427187/14351818).

For larger devices like an iPad or iPhone Pro Max in landscape, it defaults to `DoubleColumnNavigationViewStyle`.