# Docked Sidebar on iPad in portrait orientation with SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, uinavigationcontroller

SwiftUI helpfully gives you `NavigationView` which easily lets you define a sidebar and main content for iPad apps that automatically collapse for iPhones.

I have an app and everything works as expected except on iPad, in portrait mode, the sidebar is hidden by default and you are forced click a button to show it.

All I want is to force the sidebar to always be visible, even in portrait mode. And make it work the same way as the settings app.

I’m even willing to use a UIKit view wrapped for SwiftUI, but wrapping NavigationController seems very very challenging.

Is there a better way?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/57425921/14351818

Answer (score 0):

Without your specific code I can't be sure but I think you are describing the initial screen that shows on iPad. That is actually a "ThirdView". You can see it with the code below.

And I am answering the "better way" portion of your question. Which for me is a way of just "graciously" dealing with it.

```
struct VisibleSideBar2: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            List(0..<10){ idx in
                NavigationLink("SideBar \(idx)", destination: Text("Secondary \(idx)"))
            }
            Text("Welcome Screen")
        }
    }
}
```

It is even more apparent if you have a default selection in your "Secondary View" because now you have to click "Back" twice to get to the SideBar

```
struct VisibleSideBar1: View {
    @State var selection: Int? = 1
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
        List(0..<10){ idx in
            NavigationLink(
                destination: Text("Secondary \(idx)"),
                tag: idx,
                selection: $selection,
                label: {Text("SideBar \(idx)")})
        }
            Text("Third View")
        }
    }
}
```

A lot of the "solutions" out there for this just turn the `NavigationView` into a `Stack` but then you can't get the double column.

One way of dealing with it is the what is depicted in `VisibleSideBar2`. You can make/embrace a nice "Welcome Screen" so the user isn't greeted with a blank screen and then the natural navigation instincts kick in. You only see the "Welcome Screen" on iPad Portrait and on Catalyst/MacOS where Stack is unavailable.

Or you can bypass the third screen by using `isActive` in a `NavigationLink` and using the `Sidebar` as a menu like `View`

```
struct VisibleSidebar3: View{
    @State var mainIsPresented = true
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ScrollView{
                NavigationLink(
                    destination: Text("Main View").navigationTitle("Main"),
                    isActive: $mainIsPresented,
                    label: {
                        Text("Main View")
                    })
                NavigationLink("List View", destination: ListView())
                
            }.navigationTitle("Sidebar")
            //Not visible anymore
            Text("Welcome Screen")
        }
    }
}
struct ListView: View{
    var body: some View {
        List(0..<10){ idx in
            NavigationLink("SideBar \(idx)", destination: Text("Secondary \(idx)"))
        }.navigationTitle("List")
        
    }
}
```

Like I said my answer isn't really a way of "fixing" the issue. Just dealing with it. To fix it we would have to somehow dismiss the "Third Screen/Welcome Screen". Then manipulate the remaining `UISplitViewController` (Several SO questions on this) to show both the SideBar/Master and the Detail View.

In `UIKit` it seems to have been done a lot, if you search SO, you will find a way to create a `UISplitViewController` that behaves like `Settings`.

Comment: Thanks, the `UISplitViewController` part is probably the most helpful part for me here.

My problem isn't that I don't have a good starting screen. I don't want the menu column to ever be hidden, even in portrait mode. Looks like that isn't possible with just SwiftUI for now. I'll just wait for WWDC at this point.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/69350695/5356455