# Unwanted SplitView on modal view displayed on iPad

Tags: ios, swiftui, splitview

Testing my first SwiftUI app on iPad, I discovered that the modal views I display from my ContentView are displayed as Split views on the iPad, with the UI being truncated on the master side and the detail side is empty.

I did check both posts here :

[Unwanted SplitView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57425921/swiftui-unwanted-split-view-on-ipad) and,
[What's the equality of the UISplitView controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57398055/whats-the-equality-of-the-uisplitviewcontroller-in-swiftui/57400873#57400873)

But their solution of applying the `.navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle)` to the NavigationView does not work for me :

I display my modals through user input (tap of a button) using the following method :
When a button is pressed, an Int value is passed to a local var (`modalViewCaller`) and then to the `sheetContent()` function.
Here is the end of my `var body: some View` and the following `sheetContent` func :

```
              } // END of main VStack
                .sheet(isPresented: $isModalPresented, content: sheetContent)
} // END of body

// modalViewCaller is the Int var I set upon button tap

    @ViewBuilder func sheetContent() -> some View {
        if modalViewCaller == 1 {
            firstModalView()
        } else if modalViewCaller == 2 {
            secondModalView()
        } else if modalViewCaller == 3 {
            thirdModalView()
        } 
    } // END of func sheetContent
```

Then in each of these modalViews, I apply the `.navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle)` modifier to the NavigationView that encapsulate my entire view in `var body: some View`, but I get the following error :
"Type 'StackNavigationViewStyle.Type' cannot conform to 'NavigationViewStyle'; only struct/enum/class types can conform to protocols"

[image: The error displayed]

Here is the end of my NavigationView in the modals :

```
} // End of VStack
                .navigationBarItems(
                    leading:
                    Button("Done") {
                        self.saveEdits()
                        self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss() // This dismisses the view
                    } // END of Button "Done"
                )
                .navigationBarTitle("Takeoff edition")

            } // END of Navigation View
            .navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle)
            .onAppear { // assigned fetched event date, here it is available (was not in init())
            self.selectedDate = self.fetchedEvent.first?.eventDate ?? Date()
            }

        } // END of some View
```

I guess the solution posted was to apply that modifier from the ContentView NavigationView, but I don't have one (and don't want one because of all the screen real estate lost on top of my UI)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is fix (it has to be constructed, ie. `StackNavigationViewStyle()`):

```
} // END of Navigation View
.navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle()) // << here !!
```