# How to avoid to go to the NavigationLink target when using an iPad?

Tags: swift, swiftui

if I have an app with some master/detail view with the following code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            NavigationLink(destination: DetailView()) {
                Text("Go to details")
            }
        }
    }
}

struct DetailView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello, world!")
            .padding()
    }
}
```

The problem here is, that I want that also on the iPad the user first need to see the master page and not directly the detail view. But by default if you start the app it looks like this:

[image]

How to keep the master view open when the app starts on the iPad?

Comment: You could check the device type and if it's .pad you show the master page

Comment: Could you add some sample code? Then I would accept it as an answer.

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/61591692/12299030?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SwiftUI: unwanted split view on iPad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57425921/swiftui-unwanted-split-view-on-ipad)

Answer (score 0):

You could check the device type, if it's .pad then you show the master page:

```swift
if UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .pad{
//Show master page
}
```